# fsck single disk from Raid 0 lvm

Tags: lvm, fsck, nas

My NAS (Seagate Blackarmor) is refusing to connect to the network after a fsck. I assume the root filesystem (stored on flash) might have been corrupted somehow after running fsck.
The setup was a Raid 0 array with 2x2TB drives.

Edit: it might have actually been mdadm with linear span.

I have a USB<->SATA/IDE dock for accessing the disk drives on my laptop, but no way of connecting two drives at the same time.

The data stored on it is not critical but it reaches ~3TB and would like to still have it or at least compare it against another backup. I can also try soldering a TTL-UART converter on the board and work from there. NAS is based on Debian Lenny, I think.

Is there any way to check the integrity on each drive or remove the fsck flag without the other drive?

Are there any other ways to do this? Like image each one drive and use LVM on another system. Don't have enough space for this though. Or maybe buy another SATA-USB adapter.

**Edit**

**This is how I did it, just one of the possibilities**

The two 3.5" SATA drives were installed in a Win7 desktop machine and booted up an Ubuntu virtual machine inside Oracle VBox.
The (raw) drives needed to be set up prior to starting the VM:

*VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "FILENAME" -rawdisk "\.\PhysicalDrive#"*

Linux recognized the RAID and LVM setup right away ('Disks' utility) and offered to mount them. The system partition had 1GB and **the entire /etc folder was missing** plus other several files from /bin and /sbin. After a chkdsk some files were recovered in lost+found.

In the mean time all the files on the NAS drives were synchronized with my other backup.

I then searched for a raw image of the machine (Seagate Blackarmor) and extracted the missing files from the downloaded *.tar.gz archive.
I haven't tested booting it yet but obviously some configuration will be missing: ip address, samba shares, mdadm.conf.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to check a single drive's integrity and there would be little point since you need both to recover the data. If the Blackarmor used mdadm for the drives (possibly with LVM) then you could in theory mimic this setup with both drives attached via SATA-USB adapters to one Linux machine (which could be a VM). But it might be hard to do unless you know the prior setup, which Seagate may have kept proprietary...

Comment: It was a standard unix mdadm / lvm setup, I had written the commands for mounting on the flash partition inside a text file.

Comment: worth looking [here](https://sidfishes.wordpress.com/2014/03/07/how-to-seagate-blackarmor-data-recovery-after-datavolume-failed-error/) if you haven't already...

Comment: Just for clairty are you actually using LVM's raid or is it `md` raid?

Comment: and definitely look at the [Linux RAID Recovery wiki](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_Recovery)

Comment: One drive mounted inside a Debian VM is listed as having 4 partitions, each one a "Linux RAID member". I will try to get them both mounted. I should mention that I expect the data to be intact on the drives, that's not the issue.